# Buscar palabras entre comillas

Tags: python

Necesito sacar la palabra y los dos numeros en negrita de un string para pasarlo a un array para poder seleccionarlo mas tarde.
He pensado en las expresiones regulares en python utilizando la clase re pero no encuentro la forma

('{"id":192, "result":["**on**","**50**","**16777215**"]}\r\n', (0, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))

La solucion seria algo como:

```
import re
Palabras[] = re.split(**PATRON_QUE_ME_FALTA**, Frase)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre tienes una tupla en la que el primer elemento es una cadena de la forma:

> '{.., "result": algo, ...}'

Entonces tienes la representación válida de un diccionario Python y en este caso no necesitas expresiones regulares, puedes usar el método [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), versión segura de `eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval

>>> datos = ('{"id":192, "result":["on","50","16777215"]}\r\n', (0, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
>>> diccionario = literal_eval(datos[0])
>>> palabras = diccionario["result"]
```

En este caso `palabras` es una lista ya que `'["on","50","16777215"]'` es la representación válida de una lista de Python, podemos acceder a sus elementos mediante indexado, recorrerla con un `for`, etc:

```
>>> palabras
['on', '50', '16777215']
>>> palabras[0]
'on'
>>> palabras[1]
'50'
>>> palabras[2]
'16777215'
```

Comment: Necesito meter las 3 variables en un array para poder acceder a cada una independientemente, ¿Como lo hago?
Para poder hacer
>>> palabras[1]
50

Comment: @Jose `palabras` ya es una lista (lo que podríamos llamar un  "array" en Python) porque está evaluada por `ast.literal_eval` y se encarga de construir el objeto Python correspondiente. Puedes obtenerlas indexando. He editado la respuesta para ver a que me refiero.

Comment: cierto, lo habia intentado,pero algo tendria mal que me fallaba, ya me va bien, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con:

```
(?:'.*?')|(?:\".*?\")
```

Este patrón satisface las letras o números que se encuentren entre comillas.
Para usarlo en Python puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
import re
frase = '"on", "50", "16777215" "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"'
re.findall(r"(?:'.*?')|(?:\".*?\")", frase)
```

Con este código obtenemos una lista de las palabras que el patrón satisface:

```
['"on"', '"50"', '"16777215"', '"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"']
```